# Best approach for processing a large number of messages from Azure Service Bus

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a scenario where I need to process a significant number of messages from Azure Service Bus queues/topics. I will be collecting report data from mobile devices and storing it in a database.

For the collection process, I can either provide a REST API, or mobile devices can interact directly with Azure Service Bus using the AMQP protocol. This approach offers greater speed and reduces round-trip overhead.

My objective is to create a separate queue/topic for each tenant, with each queue/topic containing different types of report data. I prefer using topics because I can create multiple subscriptions and apply filters for each report type.

However, the challenge lies in efficiently processing messages from all these topics. I have considered two main options: Azure Functions or a BackgroundService in .NET, which would be deployed to a virtual machine (VM). My goal is to process messages in batches, such as handling 100 messages at a time, to prevent overwhelming the database.

Here are the options I'm considering:

Creating a background service in .NET that runs every 10-15 minutes to fetch all the topics from the Service Bus namespace and process them. However, I am concerned about parallel processing, as I want to avoid thread starvation when processing all the topic subscriptions in parallel. Additionally, database locking could be an issue, impacting processing speed.

Creating a message processor for each topic in a loop and dynamically adding processors for newly added topics. I am concerned that this approach may suffer from the same processing challenges and could lead to high resource consumption.

Using Azure Functions with a time trigger, which performs a similar task as option 1. I already have a dedicated VM for running background services, so I would consider this if it proves to be the best solution, even if it introduces some additional cost.

Dynamically creating a function for each topic within the same Function App. However, I don't think it's possible.

I'm seeking advice on the best approach, or if there is another alternative. My primary concern is ensuring the fast and efficient processing of messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage IaC to create a topic per tenant whenever you need. Use the same approach to create an Azure Function App for each tenant too. Whenever you onboard a new tenant, run the code to create the required services.

I would use Azure Functions to dequeue and process the messages. All you have to do is proper setup the max concurrent calls / sessions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-concurrency#static-concurrency

About the database, if the goal is to support millions of devices, I would use a noSQL for that and maybe aggregate results in a relational database for reporting purposes only.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my SAAS app needs a listener for each tenant in Azure Service Bus. Due to cost constraints, I can't have a separate Function app for each tenant, I seek an efficient solution: a single function app with multiple functions, a background service with all topic listeners, or a time-triggered function app or a background service to process all topics. What do you recommend? Also I do want to use noSql (cosmos db). Do you think that would avoid all the db locking?

Comment: You'd better do some Proof of Concept and validate which option better suits your needs. I would go with what I said

Comment: Sure, do you have any link that explains creating a function app for each tenant dynamically?